# PHPQuery Select all values from dropdown

Tags: php, phpquery

I need to get all the values of a dropdown in an array based upon the `id` of the dropdown using PHPQuery.

The following is the HTML:

```
<select name="semester" id="semester" class="inputtxt" onChange="javascript:selectSemester(this, this.form);">
    <option value="">-- Select your Semester --</option>
    <option value="2nd" selected>2nd</option>
    <option value="4th" >4th</option>
    <option value="6th" >6th</option>
    <option value="8th" >8th</option>
    <option value="SE1" >SE1</option>
    <option value="SE3" >SE3</option>
    <option value="SE5" >SE5</option>
    <option value="SE7" >SE7</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:

```
$semesters = $all['#semester'];

foreach ($semesters as $semester) {
    echo pq($semester)->text();
    echo '<br>';
}
```

But I get only a single output with all the values concatenated. How do I get each value as separate element in an array?

Comment: you would just iterate over `#semester option`

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am doing the same on my code

Comment: do it in jquery or javascript and post it to PHP .. huh ?

Comment: Not possible. I am getting the html in PHP using CURL.

Comment: I mean to change `#semester` option to `#semester option` - do you see the difference? It's css if you're not aware.

Comment: The PHPQuery library hasn't been maintained in 4 years. You might want to use more recent alternatives like DOM-Query (https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query).

Comment: Do you have the control over the values set that way? What I mean is, can you change the values 2nd , 4th to "2nd-" , ''4th-" ? You see where i am getting at right? That way you can split the single string to array based on the delimiter "-" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works fine for me:

```php
// include part...

$ids = array();

$raw = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8000/test.html"); // your url

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($raw);

phpQuery::selectDocument($doc);

/** @var DOMElement $opt */
foreach (pq('#semester > option') as $opt) {
    $ids[] = ($opt->getAttribute('value'));
}

print_r($ids); // check if the array has the values stored
```

So result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 2nd
    [2] => 4th
    [3] => 6th
    [4] => 8th
    [5] => SE1
    [6] => SE3
    [7] => SE5
    [8] => SE7
)
```

BTW, you can use `$doc['#semester > option']` instead of `pq('#semester > option')`, both variants works fine. If you need to omit some `option` - you'd make filter based on `option` attributes, like `if ($opt->getAttribute('value') != "")`.

Answer (score 4):

quick trick before you reinvent the wheel, use simple_html_dom, you can find it in  http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ this class has being extremely useful in the past and you can even modify it to either use it with CURL or a string containing HTML code.

You will be able to search for objects (tags) or IDs and get the contents of the tag, or iterate in more friendly way.

Answer (score 4):

This code should work. Use the target as `"#semester option"` instead of `"#semester"`.

```
$semesters = $all['#semester option'];

foreach ($semesters as $semester)
{
  echo pq($semester)->text();
  echo '<br> newline';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its easy , you need to select the selector with id and iterate it using the  tag , create an empty array and store the values in it using a foreach iterator.

```
$semsterr = array();  //empty Array

//use the option tag for iteration
foreach (pq('select#semester option') as $opt) { 
    $semsterr[] = pq($opt) -> text(); 
 // $semsterr[] = pq($opt) -> attr('value'); in case you need the value
}

print_r($semsterr); // check if the array has the values stored
```

Answer (score 3):

You must check the value before add in array.
Like...

```
$sem = array();

foreach (pq('#semester option') as $opt) { 

     if(pq($opt) -> val() != '')
     {
      $sem[] = pq($opt) -> text(); 
     }
}

print_r($sem);
```

Good Luck.. ['}

Answer (score 0):

//HTML//

```
<select name="semester" id="semester" class="inputtxt" onChange="javascript:selectSemester(this, this.form);">
<option value="">-- Select your Semester --</option>
<option value="2nd" >2nd</option>
<option value="4th" >4th</option>
<option value="6th" >6th</option>
<option value="8th" >8th</option>
<option value="SE1" >SE1</option>
<option value="SE3" >SE3</option>
<option value="SE5" >SE5</option>
<option value="SE7" >SE7</option>
```

//PHP//

```
$select = $_POST['semester'];
$count = count($select);
$i = 0;
while($i =< $count)
{
  $i++;
  echo $_POST['semester'][$i]
}
```